# Webpack can't deal with web3.js

Tags: web3js, javascript

My web app uses `web3.js` v. 1.4.0 and for module bundling I make use of Webpack v. 5.45.0.

```
// index.js (the entry point of my app)
import * as Web3 from 'web3';
```

An attempt to launch webpack results in errors like these:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@ethersproject/signing-key/lib.esm/elliptic.js
> 47:25 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (47:25) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> ```
> | }
> |
> > var minimalisticAssert = assert;
> |
> | function assert(val, msg) {
> ```
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/buffer/index.js 184:9 Module parse failed:
> Unexpected token (184:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this
> file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> ```
> | Object.setPrototypeOf(Buffer, Uint8Array)
> |
> > function assertSize (size) {
> |   if (typeof size !== 'number') {
> |     throw new TypeError('"size" argument must be of type number')
> ```

It is like Webpack trips up over the word `assert`. What can serve as a reason of this behavior?